# AVAudioPlayer Playing Sequence of Songs Loops Same Song with No Sound

Tags: ios, asynchronous, avaudioplayer

I've been trying to work through this bug for about 24 hours altogether now.
I have a simple music player that loads up some songs, then plays one song after another.

The problem is that, randomly, didFinishPlayingAudio will not be called at the end of the song. Instead, the same song will loop back to the beginning with no sound output, which makes my music player critically flawed!

Recently I realized that AVAudioPlayer's play function is asynchronous, and I suspect that this is the problem.
I went over my code and checked that the player was stopped before being released, and that the new one was retained properly. Everything works fine, except for this occasional severe bug. When I scrub on the progress bar, the music will play again, and from reading around I think that this has to do with the right audio player re-associating itself as the main player.

I attempted to use ObjectAL in order to get around this problem, but the problem with that is that the status bar Play icon will simply NOT go away unless I disable receiving remote control events, which is not acceptable for a music player. However, if there is a good way to turn off the play icon, this would also be a solution to my nasty bug!

Thank you so much if you read this far!! Hoping for some thoughts on this, thanks SO!

Comment: Solution: Turns out I was inadvertently repeatedly-calling `AVAudioPlayer`'s `playing` method. Despite already having read Apple's explicit warning to not do this, the code structure at the time was in fact sneakily polling this method, unbeknownst to me